# Dark Kamehameha?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

I was curious about the use of the dark kamehameha. So far I know that color pigment to an energy move doesn't really matter and in most cases in DBZ it's a bit of a design trope to signify the uniqueness of that move to that character.

`Black` & `Mira`(from Dragon Ball XV the game) are the only two characters portrayed to have a dark kamehameha technique.

Since the title is changed I was wondering if it uses something else other than ki. Perhaps dark god ki? Or demon ki?

Has there been any elaboration on the technique? Or is it just another trope like Freeza having a pink destructo disk?

Comment: Any insight on this? Anyone?

Comment: Maybe @pablo knows he's super active on the dbs scene

Comment: I dont think they elaborated anything about this, and I just think they mean the ki comes from an evil user. Sometimes the z fighters says "I feel an evil ki". Well, I guess that dark kamehameha was made with the ki of an user with evil ki